# Cylinder Texturing problem

Tags: texturing, uv

I made a barrel out of a cylinder and want to texture it. Can I somehow UV unwrap one column to texture that one and "clone" the other (31) columns to have the exact same texture?

If I UV unwrap the entire barrel I get 10 different (distorted) strings of small faces and the texture quality sucks.

I hope I described the barrel correctly. I put 6 loop cuts horizontal through the cylinder, set some parts in and rounded it off (which I think caused the distorted UV unwrap.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How have you unwrapped the barrel?  Have you marked any seams?  Have you used follow active quads?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, what I would do is delete all but one "tile" of the barrel, then make it a circular array.

[image: Barrel array]

Below you can see the Empty inside being used by the Array Modifier. It is rotated 11.25° (360° / 32 tiles).
Enabling "Merge" on the modifier means the tiles will be connected when the modifier is applied.

[image: Barrel array - wireframe]

UV unwrap *before* applying your modifier.